# Collecting user specific data from other opened tabs

Tags: php, curl, cookies, tabs

I'm trying to verify my users to see if they are the same users from another site.

How this is supposed to work:
The user will log in to his account, lets say a phpbb forum from another tab.
I will get the user name from the cookies and return this information to my website so now I can register that user as, this user has "examplenickname" in the xxx phpbb forum.

I got a few brilliant ideas to work this out, tried them and failed.

So I am  stuck and would like some tips to solve this problem

Comment: Cookies usually come with a restriction that the browser will only provide that cookie back to the site that set it. Although you would like to use other sites' cookies in a constructive way, malicious sites could easily use them for identity theft and all sorts of other mischief.

Comment: Thanks, so is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

get the users IP, save them to a databse and compare the entries,

see also 'REMOTE_ADDR' in $_SERVER

Comment: Well that would work if I owned the 2 forums. However I own only mine, the one I am gonna get the data from is not owned by me so I can't do that.

Comment: oh, i assumed that. however, if you dont have access to both sites, there is (thankfully) no way to do this